Get display mode of product or product variation where an 'add to cart form' is used in hook_form_alter for the add_to_card_form
I'm using Drupal 10 and the commerce module. I'm using a product display mode 'card' that uses the variations 'add to cart form' format. In hook_form_alter I am hiding the quantity field:
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
if (strpos($form_id, 'commerce_order_item_add_to_cart_form_commerce_product_') === 0) {
$form['quantity']['widget'][0]['value']['#type'] = 'hidden';
}
}
This works fine, but the problem is that it is obviously hiding the field for every view mode. I would like to only hide it for a my 'card' view mode.
How can I get the display view mode of the product (or product variation) where the the 'add to cart form' is used.
